# Concat alias of column names and variable inside the select

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I want to concat the alias I'm using in the select with a variable. Something like:

```
DECLARE @var1 as Date
set @var1 = '1/06/2021'

select (column1 + column2) AS ('Values at date ' + cast(@var1 as nvarchar)) from MyTable
```

But without dynamic select since we are using Reporting Services and EntityFramework and it needs to know the numbers of columns the procedure will return

Comment: Something is wrong with your data model if your column names are encoding dates.

Comment: Seems like the column's name should be an expression in your SSRS tablix/matrix then.

Comment: Yes. It's an equation. And we want the column name of that equation to have that name

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the command string and 'exec' it with the command

```
DECLARE @var1 as Date
set @var1 = '1/06/2021'

declare @StrSelect nvarchar(4000)='Values at date '+CAST(@var1 as nvarchar)

exec('select  column1 + column2 as ['+@StrSelect+'] from MyTable')
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help, but i don't want that. It something like this: select column1 + column2 AS ('Values at date ' + cast(@var1 as nvarchar) )  from MyTable I want to concatenate the variable with the alias